# How to use the File System Events API in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift, fsevents

maybe my search terms are not good today, but i can't find a simple example how to use the FSEvents in swift.

I have a cocoa application that displays contents from a file. When the file is changed outside of my application i have to mark the reload-button in another color. I thing FSEvents is the right place to look for this, or should I use another API?

Can you give me an example of how to revive an event when a file has changed the content?

Thank you very much.

Comment: maybe try this? https://github.com/gurinderhans/SwiftFSWatcher

Comment: Oh thanx. That looks like a cool module. I'll will play with it this week.

Answer (score 4):

After looking again I found this little Library, that works on files, too:
https://github.com/Eonil/FileSystemEvents