# How can you detect file changes with a OSX Library directory?

Tags: macos, file

You can use [NSMetadataQuery](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMetadataQuery_Class/index.html) to detect any file changes within the home directory of a user. However it seems like it doesn't index and therefor detect any file changes in the users Library path.

Luckily for my purpose I know exactly where my file is and I like to know if the files changes and react on it. Do I need to right my own listener class? That will mimic the behavior of NSMetadataQuery by checking if the modification date changes or is there a simpeler way?

```
    var resource: AnyObject?
    fileURL?.getResourceValue(&resource, forKey: NSURLContentModificationDateKey, error: nil)
    if let fileDate = resource as? NSDate {
        println(fileDate)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to watch a single file, you can use [libdispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355144/file-monitoring-using-grand-central-dispatch) or [kqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343833/cocoa-monitor-a-file-for-modifications).

For watching folders, there's the [FSEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048348/how-to-use-the-file-system-events-api-in-swift) API.